# How do I use Hpricot to search the inner_text of all elements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, hpricot

I would like to use Hpricot to scan the `inner_text` of all elements, and know what element is currently being scanned. However, each approach I have taken leads to a recursion. Is there a built-in function to do this with Hpricot (or Nokogiri)? The code below just scans one level down:

```
@t = []
doc = Hpricot(open("some html doc"))
(doc/"html").each do |e|
  e.children.each do |child|
    if child.is_a?(Hpricot::Text)
      @t << child.to_s.strip
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Why not use XPATH? Have u tried it yet?

Comment: Show us some sample HTML, and what you expect to have returned.

Comment: You can walk every node in a document, but that is terribly inefficient, resulting in very slow processing for large pages. Also, depending on the tags in the document, grabbing every text node can result in accumulating a lot of empty text consisting of only whitespace that isn't displayed in the document by the browser. Instead you should target specific nodes using CSS or XPath selectors. Also, Hpricot isn't overly stable; I'd strongly recommend looking at Nokogiri or Ox instead.

Comment: Also, scanning the inner_text of the `<body>` tag will contain the text of all child nodes, resulting in a very confusing output as you descend into those children and extract their text along with the text of all their child nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure exactly *why* you want to collect all text nodes (perhaps there is a more efficient solution), this should get you started:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('doc'))

doc.at_css("body").traverse do |node|
  puts "***#{node.name}"
  puts node.text
end
```

It uses Nokogiri's `traverse` which will visit all nodes under your starting node.